# Multi-Touch in Silverlight - doesn't recognizes the touch point

Tags: silverlight, multi-touch

I'm having this Silverlight project which I'm working on. I'm currently trying to add Multi-Touch functionality to it, and I'm having difficulties.
It seems like the system doesn't recognizes the touch point immediately when I'm touching down on a point, but only when I'm releasing it.
This affects the map control I have - its not supporting pan, and the zoom doesn't work properly.
I suspect that this might be because of a Context Menu on Right Click that I use (to be specific, it's Telerik's RadContextMenu).
Can anybody tell me what is wrong or what is interfering the Multi-Touch behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're setting the windowless param to:

```
<param name="windowless" value="true" />
```

Apparently multi-touch functionality doesn't work when using this setting, along with other things:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838156%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Sadly, it looks like all of the official documentations doesn't mention the multi-touch functionality limitations.